# Unable to See Partition While Installing Windows XP

Tags: windows, windows-xp, hard-drive, partitioning

Sorry if this has been asked and answered before.

I have a 500 GB HDD that had three partitions and am looking to combine into one so I can re-distribute the space and reinstall WinXP and W7 for a dual boot.  In XP, I deleted and combined two of the partitions into one.  After rebooting, I only saw the main partition and not the other part of my HDD.  I combined and formatted in WinXP Disk Management. I am looking to combine into one so I can redistribute the space and reinstall the two OS.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Please post a screenshot of the disk within disk management

Comment: Problem solved. I was using an older Windows XP installation disc. I used a newer disc that had SP2 and it saw all my partitions.